# How to speed up the mysql query when I have million records and have to fetch record in slabs of 50?

Tags: mysql, performance

Say, I've table with 100,000 rows, I want to fetch rows in slabs of 50 with a particular Where clause

Standard way of doing this:  select * from table where userid=5 limit 50 offset 90500;

This runs awefully slow.
Cause: All 100,000 rows are analyzed first and Limit is applied at the last stage.

Any thoughts how to speed this up. Anyone ?

Comment: Does the ORDER matter? If you `ORDER BY` the primary key it may be  faster.

Comment: any particular reason you need to drill until offset `90,500`?

Answer (score 1):

Putting an index on "userid" should really help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a primary key in the order by as galz says e.g order by id assuming your table has the column id
2. Alternatively, try use an index field (generalization of 1)
3. You may also use partitions

Answer (score 0):

1 - Using ORDER BY you can improve, but no so much;

2 - Enabling the cache and then selecting from the cache, may improve the query;

3 - Setting an index helps, but no so much too.